# Does a married woman going through the conversion process need to cover her hair?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

A married Jewish woman is required to cover her hair.

If a woman that is married is going through the conversion process does she have to cover her hair?

Comment: She doesn't have to do any Mitzvot (save 7) as she isn't Jewish.

Comment: Do you mean while she's training for conversion or while she's undergoing the actual conversion?

Comment: She should ask her sponsoring rabbi at what point it makes sense to cover her hair. But those who are serious about an Orthodox conversion (presumably a conversion with their husbands) usually do start covering their hair prior to the beis din.

Comment: It's noteworthy to throw out there that she's not halachically married until she converts and goes through kiddushin and nisuin.

Answer (score 3):

She should cover her hair the same way she keeps kosher -- she's not obligated as of right now, but she needs to get used to the lifestyle to make sure she's prepared for it. (It will also give her time to get used to the very different habit/sensation, for when she is obligated.)

(As to exactly what sort of hair covering is required -- or if there are leniencies about that -- that's a different question.)

Comment: Not sure that's a good proof. As soon as she converts she's immediately obligated to keep kosher. She's not obligated to cover her hair until she gets remarried halachically as a Jew (and to a Jew). Otherwise, I would think that she's *k'katan shenolad dami* and no more obligated than any other never-married Jewish woman.

Comment: @Loewian, right, but I imagine that in most cases of someone married converting, that'll happen soon after conversion.

Comment: @msh210 right, but I've never met a Jewish woman who practiced hair covering before getting married.

Comment: @Loewian presumably her husband is either already Jewish, or preparing to convert. In such cases, I've seen them do a halachic wedding almost immediately after the conversion -- because we wouldn't allow this halachically-unmarried couple to be secluded together.

Comment: The answer is good from a prudential point of view, but I don't think halachically there's any ruling one way or the other. A person in this situation should ask their rabbi or beis din for guidance. If the rabbi believes that the convert is completely committed to complete observance and will certainly cover her hair after she is converted and married, then perhaps he might be comfortable telling her to wait until the wedding. But it would certainly make sense to get used to doing it...(as with all the other mitzvos).